# Track a visitor with cookies PHP

Tags: php, cookies

The scenario would be the following: a user is landing to my website and is getting a cookie and together with other parameters(referrer, page_id, IP-Address, landing time etc) should be saved to database. If the same visitor is accessing another page what is different than the landing page all this information should be updated.
What could be those PHP functions what would let me to handle in an elegant way this task?

Comment: Do you have any **particular** question?

Comment: Looks like he's trying to save the header into a DB, or something. Maybe.

Comment: I haven't been working so long with cookies so I don't know how should I aboard this problem and every suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

1. [setcookie()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)
2. [$_COOKIE[]](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

All cookies are available for every page on the same domain, unless you specify otherwise.

**edit**: Looks like you want to use the [$_SERVER](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) magic variable.

Comment: this is what I'm really interested if the cookie is available on every page or it has to be created.

Comment: thanks! is a good starting point.

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice write-up on cookies. Check out the part [about domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path). Good luck!